# Does object sealed in an airless place weigh more?

Tags: mass, weight

In a case where you vacuum your items in those airless bags (space bags), do they weigh more? Or is it just a feeling because of increase in density due to decrease in volume?

Comment: I don't understand your question.
Do you mean when you put clothes into a plastic bag and then you suck the air out of it with a vacuum cleaner?

Comment: @Harold yes that is exactly what i mean, i tried to make the question a bit general so it can fit into a more general case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any every day life purpose, they weight the same. But there is a difference:

**Weight vs mass**

*Weight* and *mass* are different things. The mass is a measurement of the amount of matter (alternatively, the opposition of a body to change trajectory), whereas the weight is the strength with the Earth pulls objects towards it. The difference is subtle: an astronaut in orbit has mass, but no weight; a scale measures weight, but it transforms it to mass.

Now think of a helium balloon as it goes up. Why does it go up, if it has some mass, and thus the Earth pulls it downwards? Because its weight is less than the air around, so the Earth is pulling from it more, and so it has preference.

Or, in other words, Archimedes principle holds. If you measure it, the balloon has negative weight.

**Feathers and lead**

If you *weight*  a ton (mass) of feathers and a ton of lead, you will get that the lead is slightly heavier: the air around the feathers is pushing it upwards more than the air around the lead, because feathers take much more space, and thus, more air helps with buoyancy.

**A bag full of air**

Now we get to your question. We have two rigid identical boxes, one empty, and other full of air. The second one will weight a bit more, and also have more mass. The effect of the air is the same for both, as they have the same volume.

Now, take two soft plastic bag and fill one with air. Again, the mass of the one with air will be greater, but the weight will be the same. Why? Because the one that is empty has also a smaller volume.

Do a thought experiment: take the rigid box full with air and put it on a scale. Carefully open the lid. Nothing has changed, the weight is the same. In the soft bags, the extra mass added by the bag gets exactly cancelled out by the buoyancy (by Archimedes' principle) provided by the extra volume.

**Perception**

All this efects are small. For volumens of a liter, we are talking about differences of 1g. As you righfully note, the *density* increases, and we tend to feel it as heavier.

Answer (score 1):

The actual weight of the object itself (without air in it) will remain unchanged. Yet before you sucked out the air, the total weight of the thing (object + air inside it) was less.

So it's similar to a balloon case. With air in it, the balloon falls down more slowly than without, because the total weight decreases, and it's only partially due to the increase in size. Helium-filled balloon goes up, because it's total weight is less than the air outside, so despite the gravity still working on the helium-filled balloon, the air around is heavier, so the balloon is pushed up by the air (like oil by water).

Answer (score 0):

An old question. But reading through the other answers, it seems not precisely answered, or at least not concisely to the principle being queried.

The answer, from a physics point of view, is NO; a container WITHOUT AIR does not increase weight of an object inside said container.

To answer the question as to why one might perceive the increase in weight:

1. What Davidmh was saying is that without the air it's buoyancy is less, and is perceived as greater weight. Though this will rarely have much of an effect upon your perception, and unlikely to be noticeable with such a small bag of clothes.
2. In addition to this principle, is the higher density principle mentioned by the OP, which is often perceived by people as greater weight; the mind's consideration of the average density to weight ratios.
3. Further to this, if you were to take a large bag of feathers and lift it up, a person will often perceive it as lighter than a lead chunk of the same weight. The lead chunk puts greater pressure on a smaller area of your hand, making you perceive a greater effect than the feathers, which often the subconscious mind translates to weight.

Now, for the long answer as to why:

Often, we unconsciously associate hard with heavier, which is why many people become aware of the incongruity when they see and feel a hard object that weights very little. If it's far enough outside the general principles of density/weight ratio to make it noticeable to the conscious mind, we become interested with the difference.

But highly connected to this is the principle of density and rigidity effect in physics. When you have a pliable bag of clothes with a deal of air in them, they feel softer and thus lighter to the subconscious perception; their effect is minimized in relation to the forces exerted upon your hand (i.e. pressure, leverage, force of momentum, etc.). When you suck out the air, the bag and contents becomes more dense, or harder, and the bag may become more rigid, altering the effect on your hand or handling of it, and thus your perception of its weight.

But these answers, although interconnected to the physical world, are only fully answered when reaching outside the scope of physics, and delves into the study of human mental processes, psychology, and pattern recognition. More uniquely: haptic perception and extended physiological proprioception, and approximative pattern (re)cognition short of apophenia within cognitive neurosciences.

In the former case, you feel the differences of the bag, with and without air, by extension... your haptic sense of its potential and properties. But in the latter case, your mind presents two psychological perceptions for the two states based on your haptic perceptions and understanding of associations between physical traits(i.e. weight/density ratio); your mind's best attempt to categorize the difference in the simplest terms (weight) in relation to how you must act or treat them.  If the bag and clothing became significantly harder, your mind might have passed along the perception of increased density over the dominant sensation of weight, and you might instead be asking if a bag of clothes in a vacuumed bag had solidified into a harder form of matter.

The latter encompasses a number of areas of study: (physio-psychological and Evolutionary psychology, cognitive neurosciences, etc.) traits that help humans and animals survive better. These studies consider the premise that the unconscious/subconscious mind presents perceptions in a reduced, simplistic form to the animal to make conscious choices upon, as apposed to overcomplicated ones that may lead the animal to not survive through over-contemplation, indecision, and confusion. The answer may not be the correct one, but the animal can make a choice that leads to survival regardless, rather than being caught trying to make sense of potential dangers in indecision.  In relation to the question at hand, your mind makes a judgement (reduced to the factor of "weight") based upon various physics factors: its attempt to reduce the equation to its simplest relevant form which you can make a choice upon. Heavier, harder things are handled differently, or they could cause injury. Your mind is telling you the bag without air posses a slightly greater risk than your mind generally considers a bag of clothes to be: handle with more care! You innately understand the increase of density and rigidity, but the increased leverage of handling the now condensed clothes increases forces upon your senses and are translated as heavier weight. Your mind prioritizing that as more significant than the density/rigidity itself.

As you've probably guessed, this principle isn't confined to conclusions of just weight. Things may seem harder, or softer, or some other characterization by the mind to accomplish the reduced factor upon which your conscious mind is to act. If, for example, you are presented with a potential risk with things which are soft, your mind will similarly tell you the higher risk is softer than something that is just as soft, but which doesn't seem to pose the same risk.

Your mind can also be fooled into bypassing or flip-flopping this warning method. If, for example, we consider a vat of Non-Newtonian fluid; say corn starch in water or a pond of quicksand. If you don't know it's quicksand until you begin to sink, you immediately are told by the unconscious mind that this stuff is too soft, you need to get out. Whereas, moments before you thought it hard. The stuff may not even be all that soft, but as you sink, the mind is now presenting a "too soft" danger warning that may lead to panic if no solution to escaping it is at hand.  However, if you saw a vine to pull yourself out, only to find the fluid is now too thick--or not soft enough--to get out of as quickly as your unconscious mind is pushing you to.  Your mind is now telling you the danger is that the fluid won't let you escape easily, it's too thick!  The two perceptions seem to contradict each other, and they only come when the unconscious mind tells you there is danger in it being the one way or the other way as they each seem to pose a risk. And when it does that, your conscious mind is asking why it felt so soft before and not soft enough now.

While the bag of clothes isn't panic inducing, your survival unconsciousness is still making judgements to help you make safe choices all the time. It tells you the bag without air is different, which comes as a sense of increased weight and density, and you are to act on that warning by treating the harder, heavier object with more care than a usual bag of soft clothing. The fact the the "heavier" part of the unconscious warning took a little more precedence above the "harder" part of the warning was just a slightly misplaced approximation of the physical attributes of the bag to help you make a decision for safety. If it weighs more, you will handle it differently.

Throwing a loose shirt in someone's face probably won't hurt, but a heavier bag of hardened shirt might, and your mind is telling you this by suggesting greater weight. Although imprecise, it nevertheless helped you categorize the object for safety reasons that prove effective to the occasion. Without even thinking about such a scenario, you would have been less likely to handle the vacuumed bag as carelessly as one with lots of air in it. And this is good, considering throwing the bag with air will prove far less dangerous than the one without air.

For reference, look up German Psychologist Max Dessoir's "Haptic Perception" academic research into the sense of touch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_perception
For the other sciences, a quick internet or wikipedia search will provide some answers and bases for further study.